# In FOI why ACS/PTS it should be emphasized those documents are not a teaching document?

Tags: ground-instructor

In Aviation Instructor’s handbook (FOI) they said “ACS/PTS it should be emphasized those documents are not a teaching document”Is there any reason?

Comment: Welcome.  FWIW, quotation marks are generally reserved for direct, verbatim quotes.  If you intended to paraphrase your interpretation of the handbook you should leave the marks out.  That said, did 757toga quote the section you are asking about below?  If so, your interpretation is pretty much 180 out from the intended meaning.  Just sayin', read carefully!

Answer (score 2):

The [Aviation Instructor's Handbook](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/aviation_instructors_handbook/aviation_instructors_handbook.pdf) ( FAA-H-8083-9) is making the point that there is much more for the instructor to teach and the student to learn when becoming a certificated pilot (or mechanic) than teaching only what is on the test (Airman Certification Standards/Practical Test Standards - ACS/PTS).  Specifically, "*Certification tests do not represent an entire training syllabus*."

See this pertinent excerpt from page 5-5 from the Aviation Instructor's Handbook (FAA-H-8083-9):

[image]